# multiple lightbox gallery on one page

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightbox

how can i fix this? when i click "smile" it appears smile but when i click sad it also appear a smiley face.

```
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open();">SMILE<br></a>
<div id="light"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/1024px-Smiley.svg.png" width=100 height=100></div>
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open();">SAD</a>
<div id="light"><img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/MiL/kkB/MiLkkBAia.png" width=100 height=100></div>
<div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
```

CSS: fade for the close and light is for the the lightbox.

```
#fade{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    z-index:1001;
    -moz-opacity: 0.7;
    opacity:.70;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}
#light{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: -150px;
    margin-top: -100px;                 
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    background: #CCC;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow:visible;
```

javascript: for the open and close function

```
window.document.onkeydown = function (e)
{
    if (!e){
        e = event;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 27){
        lightbox_close();
    }
}
function lightbox_open(){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';  
}
function lightbox_close(){
    document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
```

Comment: you must use unique ID's, you cannot use the same ID (`light`) twice

Comment: so im goin to create a new light css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the same ID twice. You must use unique ID's.

Try this:

In the HTML, give your two `light` divs each a unique ID, for example `lightSmile` and `lightSad`.

In order to be able to use the same CSS for both lightboxes, give both boxes a class `lightbox`, and in the CSS, change the `#light` to `.lightbox`.

Finally, change the `lightbox_open()` function to the one below here.

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open('lightSmile');">SMILE<br></a>
<div class="lightbox" id="lightSmile"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Smiley.svg/1024px-Smiley.svg.png" width=100 height=100></div>
<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open('lightSad');">SAD</a>
<div class="lightbox" id="lightSad"><img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/MiL/kkB/MiLkkBAia.png" width=100 height=100></div>
<div id="fade" onClick="lightbox_close();"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.lightbox{
    display: none;
    ...
}
```

**JS**

```
function lightbox_open(id){
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
    document.getElementById(id).style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block';  
}

function lightbox_close(){
    document.getElementById('lightSmile').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('lightSad').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
```

If you look at the HTML, you see that now a string of the lightbox's ID is send along when `lightbox_open()` is called.
In the function, this ID-string is supplied as a variable (between the brackets: `id`). And in the line where lightbox's  display-style is changed, this `id` is used.

In the close-function, the display-style of both the lightbox's is set back to default.

---

### UPDATE

If you have a lot of lightboxes, it's easier to access the lightboxes by classname in the close-function:

```
function lightbox_close(){
    var list = document.getElementsByClassName('lightbox');
    for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        list[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
```

And if you're willing to use **jQuery**, you can do that with one line (and probably more reliably cross-browser):

```
function lightbox_close(){
    $('.lightbox').css('display','none'); //<--------------jQuery
    document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I added quite a few things since the first post, I forgot some things. It should work now.

Comment: whoah it worked :)) thanks!. now can i add another lightboxes to this?

Comment: yes you can, but if you want a lot more it would be easier in the close function to access all the lightboxes by classname. Let me just add that, I'll let you know when the answer is updated

Comment: I've added the update for access by classname, let me know if it works

Comment: what am i goind to add if i add another lightboxes? and to your codes am i only gonna edit close?

Comment: the edit of the close-function is just so that you don't have to add every new lightbox in there. Now every lightbox (with classname "lightbox" will be closed.

Comment: the only lines you need to add for a new lightbox is in the HTML: an `<a href>` and a `<div>` with image inside it. It is important here that the `div` has class "lightbox", and that the string that is send along in the function-call in the `a href` matches the ID of the `div`, like this: `<a href="#" onclick="lightbox_open('imageID');">...</a>
<div class="lightbox" id="imageID"><img ...></div>`